# How to write an Android app as NFC handler?

Tags: android, nfc

I want to write an Android app, which is automatically opened or is at least listed as handler, when an NFC tag was detected.

I created an example app as described in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyVihl6ACmQ
but it does not work (the app is not opened).

You can find my code at https://github.com/hobber89/androidNFCHandler

As shown in the video I added the NFC permission, the NFC feature and an intent-filter.
What am I doing wrong, what is missing?

Kind regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: What is on the Tag you are trying with, is there a Ndef message? I suggest that you use the NXP Taginfo app to full scan the Tag you are using and then save the result to a file and then post the text of the file here, so we can understand the Tag you are using for testing.

Comment: Just a guess - you are calling "enableForegroundDispatch" with parameter "techLists" that is set to "android.nfc.tech.NfcV.class" which is quite unusual when trying to detect a tag (because most tags I have seen are using other technologies). Better use "null" as parameter as this is a kind of wildcard.

Comment: @Andrew

thank you for your response!
I copied the values from the YouTube example.

Now I updated the values in tech-list to all values I found on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837963/android-nfc-intent-filter-for-all-type and added more intent-filters, but it did not help.
And you can find the file from NXP Taginfo from my testing device at https://github.com/hobber89/androidNFCHandler/blob/main/files/41-4F-4A-B7-B3-59-02-E0_22-Aug.-23%2008-01-30_taginfo_scan.txt

Do you you have any more suggesstions what I can try or do you know where I can find a full working example?

Comment: @MichaelFehr

when the app is open, the tag is detected. Does the code in the MainActivity has influence on if the app is suggested as handler when an NFC tag was detected while the app is closed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I am defining only one technology in tech-list:

```
 <tech-list>
    <tech>android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable</tech>
 </tech-list>
```

the app is opened when an NFC-Tag was discovered.
The working code can be found at https://github.com/hobber89/androidNFCHandler

Answer (score 1):

I can see why your first attempt did not work.

Your code was only registering in the Manifest to be started when a Tag with a `Ndef` message on it, the Tag you are using is blank, it does not have a `Ndef` message on it.

The output from NXP Taginfo says:-

```
-- NDEF ------------------------------

# No NDEF Data Storage Populated:
```

and

```
* TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.NfcV, android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable]
```

so the Tag is capable of storing a `Ndef` message once formatted (Tag Tech `android.nfc.tech.NdefFormatable` changes to `android.nfc.tech.Ndef` when formatted)

**After your recent update**

Now your tech list is looking for all types of Tag, so will match the type of Tag you are using for testing.

On the face of it, this should work but I'm concerned that the way you added it to the manifest xml won't be parsed correctly.

I suggest the following `Activity` entry in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
                android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
        </activity>
```

This is the more normal style and what I use in one of my apps to launch my App when a Tag is presented. Possibly the only the first `intent-filter` xml Tag is process and adding the tech filter to `NDEF_DISCOVERED` and `TAG_DISCOVERED` has no effect.

**Update**

I clone your  repo and had the same problem on my phone.

After a bit of playing I found the problem

Your nfc_tech_filter.xml needs to be like:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

If you want to match Tags with different technologies you need multiple tech lists e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcA</tech>
    </tech-list>
    <tech-list>
        <tech>android.nfc.tech.NfcV</tech>
    </tech-list>
</resources>
```

This is because as the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#tech-disc) says:-

> For example, if the tag that is scanned supports MifareClassic, NdefFormatable, and NfcA, your tech-list set must specify all three, two, or one of the technologies (and nothing else) in order for your activity to be matched.

and

> Your activity is considered a match if a tech-list set is a subset of the technologies that are supported by the tag

So your NFC Tag has to match **ALL** the technologies in each list.

It is actually impossible to have a Tag that matches all the possible technologies at once

I've raise a [documentation Bug Report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/296916431) to change the miss leading example file.

Comment: Thank you also for your second response!

I think I updated the AndroidManifest as you suggested, recompiled and reinstalled the app, restarted the phone but it suggests still not the app as NFC handler when a NFC tag is detected.
After your first comment I installed the NXP Taginfo app and also this app is not shown. So maybe I must define it as default app manually, which is not possible on my phone. I will try it on another phone in the next days.

Kind regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: I cloned your Repo and tried on my phone and got the same problem, I've updated the answer that identifies the problem and how to fix it (See Updated section) and created a Android Documentation bug to fix the miss leading documentation. (In my App I only filtered for 1 tech of NfcA)